# What is sdk_version: "module_current" vs sdk_version: "system_current"?

Tags: android, android-source

I am using one library that is used `sdk_version: "module_current"` in its Android.bp file. Somewhere I saw that the library can also use `sdk_version: "system_current"`. My question is what's the difference between those and when we should which one?

I know that `system_current` has wider access but `module_current` does not.